# Power BI Slicer on Table 1 to calulate new column on other Table 2

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table `Numbers` and a slicer "num" to filter to a single number.
Then I have a second table `Exhibitors` with their exhibitorID and size.
Depending on their size I need to rate them. The rating has to depend on the slicer "num":
[image]

I need to do this with a calculated column (Expected outcome in GREEN).
Trying something like this did not work:

```
Calculated Class =
IF(Exhibitor[Space] >= max('Numbers'[num]), "A", "B")
```

Can someone help me with that calculated column?

Comment: Check out the [HASONEVALUE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/hasonevalue-function-dax) function.  And if you want the value to depend on the current filter context (selection) you must use a Measure, not a Calculated Column.

Comment: Is it not possible to use the current filter context (selection) to calculate columns?

Comment: Why don't you just use [What-if parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/desktop-what-if) for that?

Comment: I will have some complicated visuals that I can coplet better with columns. Columns dont support "What-If parameter"

Answer (score 1):

Since Calculated Columns are populated at Refreshing the data, Slicer have no impoact on Columns. Only Measures can be affected by Slicer.
So it has to be a complicated Measure for my Visuals.
Thank you.